# Javascript charAt for different transliterations in one string

Tags: javascript, transliteration, charat

I'm working on a romanizer for Korean names and I'm stuck here because it isn't a simple transliteration from A to B but a little more complex one :

Usually names are made of **3 syllables** (recognized as **3 characters** in JavaScript), the surname is the first one and it's usually followed by a first name consisting in **2 (or less often 1)** syllables.

Unfortunately family names and first names don't always have the same romanization and I need to put a "**-**" between the two syllables in the first name.

Some concrete (and artificial) examples :

- 김김김 -> Kim Gim-gim
- 이이김 -> Lee I-gim
- 이김야 -> Lee Gim-ya

To operate a distinction between the three syllables (characters) and try to make them appear, I wrote the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
function separation() {
    var str = document.getElementById("ttt").value;
    var res1 = str.charAt(0);
    var res2 = str.charAt(1);
    var res3 = str.charAt(2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res1+res2+res3;
}

var syllable_1 = {
'김' : 'Kim ',
'이' : 'Lee ',
'야' : 'Ya',
} 
var syllable_2 = {
'김' : 'Gim',
'이' : 'I',
'야' : 'Ya',
} 
var syllable_3 = {
'김' : '-gim',
'이' : '-i',
'야' : '-ya',
}

function hangul_to_roman(hangul) {
    return syllable_1[hangul.charAt(0)] + syllable_2[hangul.charAt(1)] + ( hangul.length >= 3 ? syllable_3[hangul.charAt(2)] : "" );
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="ttt" value="김김이" onBlur="separation()">

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: The problem is I only manage to get the Korean unconverted. Could anyone tell me how to correct this?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Never mind the transliteration part: you are *replacing* the innerHTML with each next new fragment. Add the strings together before writing it into `demo`.

Comment: it's better now thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is :

```
function hangul_to_roman(hangul) {
    return syllable_1[hangul.charAt(0)] + syllable_2[hangul.charAt(1)] + ( hangul.length >= 3 ? syllable_3[hangul.charAt(2)] : "" );
}
```

and you don't need the `transliteration` functions.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, yet I don't know why it still doesn't convert the Korean characters -> http://jsfiddle.net/LGRAq/3/

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LGRAq/4/ Since you use `blur` event, you have to click in the input text and then somewhere else. And you can remove `separation()`.